# mvs partial view antiforgery

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, antiforgerytoken

I have a ASP.NET MVC5 Page with a partial view. Do I need to add,  @Html.AntiForgeryToken() to both the page and the partial view? or should I only use it on the main web page and not the partial. The reason I am asking is that when I use  @Html.AntiForgeryToken() on the partial page I get an error saying  that, the  AntiForgeryToken does not match.

Does anyone know about this?

Edit 2014/10/17

@ps2goat

There is a main page without any forms, within this page exists two _partialviews which contain one form each. There are no nested forms.

_PartialForm

```
@model IEnumerable<Test.ViewModels.Report_Requirements>

@using (Html.BeginForm("ExportRequirments", "Report", FormMethod.Post,
  new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })) 
{
  @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
}
```

Comment: you need to place the token in the form that is being posted.  If you are doing your own posting with ajax, you will need to attach the token to your post data.  If you have multiple tokens being posted to the server, this error may also occur.

Comment: @ps2goat Thank you. If both the page and partial few have a form each, should I place @HTML.AntiForgeryToken() in each?

Comment: If you have several `<form>` elements on your page and you are using the default posting (clicking a button, e.g.), you will need one token in each form.

Comment: @ps2goat Thank you, I don't use my own posting, I use the submit button. When I post with only one <form> (either one out of two) it works fine, but the moment I attach the second <form> the error appears. In that case where should I look for errors?

Comment: The Error message - "The anti-forgery cookie token and form field token do not match."

Comment: you'd have to show some sample html code.  Do you have nested forms?

Comment: @ps2goat I have posted one of the forms. The other form is exactly similar to this. There are no nested forms. In the main page two _PartialViews exist. Each view contain one <form>

Comment: then it should work as long as the submit button is also in the `<form>`.  One final option is to recycle the app-- sometimes caching can give you a similar error message, especially when constantly making changes during the same IIS Express session.  I can't help you much more unless you post more code.